# Why primary key ids are not in sequence?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, rails-activerecord, heroku-postgres

My last record's primary key was 552 & when I added a new record it's primary key allotted is 584.

I'm surprised & would like to know possible reasons for this behavior.

Application Details :

- Server: Heroku hobby plan - dyno
- Database: Heroku Postgres
- Framework: Ruby on Rails

Additional Info -> I'm using rails admin panel to add new record

Comment: Is it possible records were added and deleted?  ID numbers are not reused or reset because the last record is deleted.

Comment: Sometimes when I'm doing something in a transaction and an error occured, the records are not inserted, but my id still increments

Comment: @SteveTurczyn I need to confirm if that happened since I haven't deleted any records.

Comment: Does your sequence have `CACHE` set to a value greater than 1?

Comment: @jjanes How do I check that?

Comment: @Int'lManOfCodingMystery Either I used to insert one record / 90 records at a time using rails-activerecord import & I didn't see any transaction being rollback

Comment: It's my understanding that in a transaction, it won't do anything if there's an error and thus not show any rollbacks.

Comment: In `psql`, use `\d` on the name of the sequence.

Comment: Were you able to figure it out ? I keep facing the same issue @LakhaniAliraza

Answer (score 4):

Possible reasons:

1. Some records were added+deleted
2. Inserting transaction was reverted for some reason, From [postgres manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL):

   > Note: Because smallserial, serial and bigserial are implemented using sequences, there may be "holes" or gaps in the sequence of values which appears in the column, even if no rows are ever deleted. A value allocated from the sequence is still "used up" even if a row containing that value is never successfully inserted into the table column. This may happen, for example, if the inserting transaction rolls back.
3. Corresponding sequence `table_name_seq` has `increment` more than 1 (probably not your case, sometimes is useful for sharding)

Comment: 1. No data were inserted & deleted by any of us.
2. I haven't repeated any transaction myself as all were successful in one attempt.
3. I checked my information_schema.sequence its incremented by 1